# Gradle Proguard tasks not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, proguard

I feel like I'm stupid because I can't seem to get Proguard working for my non Android Java project. I followed the documentation and that's what I've got right now:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    flatDir dirs: '/proguard6.1.1/lib'
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath ':proguard:'
  }
}

task myProguardTask(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
  injars  'in.jar'
  outjars 'out.jar'
}
```

It's imported correctly because tasks like that are working:

```
task proguardTask(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) { 
  println "proguard output"
}
```

But for some reason I'm not able to obfuscate my jars. I'd be thankful for help!

Comment: If tasks using `type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask` execute, yet your JAR produced by ProGuard from the output JAR of the build process, does not look the way you want it to look, then your proguard configuration file is misconfigured. You will have to read their documentation on that. There is minification, optimization and obfuscation and ProGuard lets you configure each. Also be aware that ProGuard can produce runtime errors. Obfuscating classes which are referred to via reflection can cause errors which only become apparent on runtime.

Comment: In any case, if you are maintaining a large business-level product, then don't expect to just enable ProGuard and everything works. You will have to configure ProGuard and expect runtime-errors, until your configuration is properly set up.